# Get the state of hdfs namenode while connecting using rpc?

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

I have an application that will get block locations of a file from namenode. I found a way to connect to namenode through RPC api, which is shown below.

```
private ClientProtocol namenode;
...
public ClientProtocol connectProxy(InetSocketAddress addr, Configuration conf)
    throws IOException {

    URI nameNodeUri = NameNode.getUri(addr);
    return NameNodeProxies.createProxy(conf, nameNodeUri,
            ClientProtocol.class, new AtomicBoolean(false)).getProxy();
}
```

By manually passing an InetSocketAddress of (host, port) of an namenode, I can connect to the namenode successfully and call the `getBlockLocations()` method.
Here is the problem, in a HA enabled environment, I need to check if the namenode is active and if it's not, I need to connect to another one, otherwise the method will throw a RemoteException that says sth like `Operation XXX is not supported in state standby`

I found in `org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer` there exists a method `getServiceStatus()`, but the below exception is thrown as I cast `((NamenodeProtocols) namenode)`

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy10 cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.protocol.NamenodeProtocols
```

And I got stuck here. Can someone help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Although it's not a direct answer to what this question was asked for, I found a way to solve my problem.
For `org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.NameNodeProxies.createProxy`, in the comment they write

> @param nameNodeUri the URI pointing either to a specific NameNode or to a logical nameservice.

Before I was passing a specific `ip:port` of a namenode as this parameter. As soon as I change that to `hdfs://<mynameservice>`, it automatically connects to the active one, and everything after works fine.

The drawback is I have no idea which namenode I'm connecting to, and I might still need a way to monitor namenodes' state in the future.

Any add-on comment or advice would be appreciated.